# Pivot table ordering and filtering

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel Workbook with two tabs - soon to be more.

The first tab is a large table containing a lot of data, the additional tabs (what I am calling view tabs) will essentially be selected data from the first tab - a sub-set of the table's columns - with various ordering.

To achieve this I am currently using a couple of pivot tables on the second tab - as I say this is the first of the 'view' tabs.

The pivot table does not need to do any summing or counting or anything like that so everything is just shown in tabular format.

The pivot table sorts alphabetically on the first column automatically - which is perfect for my needs.

I also have the following code inserted into this first view tab so that the pivot table is updated with the latest data from the 'Data' tab whenever the view tab is opened.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Me.PivotTables(1).RefreshTable
End Sub
```

When I edit a value in the data in the Data tab that is displayed in the first column of a pivot table in the view tab and then I view the view tab, the edited value is shown as updated in the view tab BUT it is moved to the bottom of the list - i.e. any edited value moves out of the alphabetical ordering in the first column and moves to the end of the list.

Editing data in any other column on the Data tab works fine.

I have an example xlsx demonstrating the problem, but it seems you can't attach files to SE posts (I hadn't noticed that in all these years!) - if anyone can point me to somewhere online that I could upload the example then I can link to it here.

Comment: If [so] allowed attachment of files, I, for one probably wouldn't be hanging out for long...There is a reason you can't attach files. Questions should include code (more than your 1 line of code)  but only the bare minimum necessary to repeat the specific problem.  (See [mcve].) The question should be kept to a minimum as well, and only 1 question per post.  (see [ask] and also [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).)

Comment: @ashleedawg You really want me to post the whole XML of the .xlsx file - I don't think so. I understand how SO works in terms of posting code, but that's not really relevant in this case.

Comment: @pnuts Unbelievable! Such a simple fix - I'd assumed that as the PT sorted based on that column anyway (rather than using source data order) there was no need to actually set a sort on it. That's sorted the problem anyway - care to move that to an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @pnuts Sorry, I must be being especially stupid today. What do you mean by "supply an A"? (Thanks for the comments re websites - encouragement is appreciated :-))

Comment: @pnuts OK, will do once the 48hrs is up. If I find my own solution I usually post it as an answer but if someone else has answered in comments I thought it would be bad form to steal their answer.

Comment: @FatMonk No **I absolutely *do not*** want you post all your code. **I do** however, expect you to take 2 minutes to visit & read links shared with you. : A question should include **as little code as possible that still produces the same problemⓜ** but all also **ALL partsⒸ needed to reproduce the problem** (like **sample input data** & a clear exampleⒺ of **expected output** or result). The **code provided should be *tested***Ⓥ to make sure it reproduces the problem. **Background info** can also help give an idea of the overall objective, thus reduce wasted time for those helping.

Comment: @FatMonk - all of this is detailed in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the links I sent, meaning you either didn't bother reading them, or didn't bother changing anything.  If these requirements don't apply to your question, *you might be in the [wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).*   More important [tips here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question). and also here: "[ask]".

Comment: @ashleedawg May I politely suggest you get off your high horse? To replicate this problem in an Excel spreadhseet would have required posting the whole Spreadsheet - i.e. this would have fulfilled the 'as little code as possible that still produces the same problem' criteria you state. The problem, as I described, was actually quite simple and your spouting of rules and regulations that simply are not relevant to the question posed just makes you look like a pedant. If you were not able to help, as it seems is the case, then simply don't take part. pnuts was able to help anyway.

Comment: @FatMonkey - Sorry Dude, the rules (and related links) are in place *for a reason*. I wasn't wasting my time on your question just for fun, but I'm not heartbroken that you don't appreciate my time.  This site takes some getting used to; user who spend more time answering than asking see the same issues. Being self-moderated, some people interpret the rules/suggestions differently than others. I really do hope you read through the FAQ's (even though there are indeed there are *a lot* of them) before your next post.  And, I'm pretty tall, so my horse is ***just*** the right height.  Good Luck!

Comment: @ashleedawg Tell you what... how about you give me an example of what code I could have posted that would have helped you point me to the answer that pnuts gave me. What kind of code sample would have satisfied your needs and helped you to help me? I'd be very interested to see that as pnuts understood what I was looking for based on the question as it was... As I have said, posting code would not have helped here - only a sample file would have helped which is not uploadable to SO. (And in case you didn't notice - I DID post the only piece of code that I thought might be relevant!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @pnuts comment, this was simply a case of applying a sort to the first column of the pivot table via the filter menu.

Now whenever the pivoted source data changes, the data in the pivot table updates and the data order is preserved - exactly as required.

(It still seems odd, however, that Excel automatically sorts the data into the pivot table in the first instance - rather than listing in source data order - but does not maintain that ordering unless the pivot table data itself is explicitly sorted).